# How is pointer to member function implemented in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers, multiple-inheritance

The pointer to member function in c++ is in three parts:

```
Offset
Address/index
virtual?
```

Offset is used for Pointer adjustment when derived object is called using `base pointer.`

How is this offset implemented? Is it pointer to some table, one table for each derived class and the table contains entries of the form `(base X, offset)`?

Also, where can I get more info about this?

Comment: This is implementation-dependent. There is no universal answer.

Comment: @RaymondChen okay, If you could tell us about the details of any implementation, that would be great. I am not looking for universal solution.

Comment: There's a discussion of various implementations of member function pointers in the writeup of ["The Fastest Possible C++ Delegates"](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7150/Member-Function-Pointers-and-the-Fastest-Possible) that is fairly easy to understand, plus there's cross compilable code that already works baked into that code.

Answer (score 15):

First you should note that a C++ method can be implemented (and is normally implemented) just as a regular function that accepts an extra hidden parameter before all other parameters, named `this`.

In other words in

```
struct P2d {
   double x, y;
   void doIt(int a, double b) {
       ...
   }
};
```

the machine code for `doIt` is the same that would be generated by a C compiler for

```
void P2d$vid$doIt(P2d *this, int a, double b) {
    ...
}
```

and a call like `p->doIt(10, 3.14)` is compiled to `P2d$vid$doIt(p, 10, 3.14);`

Given this a method pointer for a simple class that has no virtual methods **can** be implemented as a regular pointer to the method code (NOTE: I'm using `vid` for "Void of Int+Double" as a toy example of the "name mangling" that C++ compilers do to handle overloads - different functions with the same name but different parameters).

If the class has virtual methods however this is no more true.

Most C++ compilers implement virtual dispatching unsing a VMT... i.e. in

```
struct P2d {
    ...
    virtual void doIt(int a, double b);
};
```

the code for a call like `p->doIt(10, 3.14)` where `p` is a `P2d *` is the same that a C compiler would generate for

```
(p->$VMTab.vid$doIt)(p, 10, 3.14);
```

i.e. the instance contains a hidden pointer to a virtual method table that for each member contains the effective code address (assuming the compiler cannot infer that the class of `p` is indeed `P2d` and not a derived, as in that case the call can be the same as for a non-virtual method).

Method pointers are required to respect virtual methods... i.e. calling `doIt` indirectly using a method pointer on an instance derived from `P2d` is required to call the derived version while the same method pointer is instead to call the base version when used on `P2d` instances. This means the selection of which code to call depends on both the pointer and the class instance.

A possible implementation is using a trampoline:

```
void MethodPointerCallerForP2dDoit(P2d *p, int a, double b) {
    p->doIt(a, b);
}
```

and in this case a method pointer is still just pointer to code (but to the trampoline, not to the final method).

An alternative would be to store as method pointer the **index** of the method inside the VMT instead. This would be feasible because in C++ the method pointer is tied to a specific class and therefore the compiler knows if for that class there are virtual methods or not.

Multiple inheritance do not complicate things for method pointers because everything can be just resolved to a single final VMT table at compile time.

Comment: `p->P2d$VMTab[P2d$Index$doIt$vdd]` screams to be clarified.

Comment: @black: simplified the VMT explanation using a structure instead of an array (indeed the pointer/index version would require also a cast to be valid C code).

Comment: @6502 The way that you suggested, doesn't require offset. But then why method pointer is 1 byte bigger in size than normal function pointer in g++?

Answer (score 1):

This is a comment regarding 6502's answer, but I lack reputation.

> a method pointer for a simple class that has no virtual methods can be implemented as a regular pointer to the method

I believe this statement is incorrect because multiple inheritance complicates things.  Consider this code:

```
struct A {
    int a;
    void f() {
        // use a
    }
};

struct B {
    int b;
    void g() {
        // use b
    }
};

// C objects may look like this in memory:
//
//     |-----|
//     |  A  |
//     |-----|
//     |  B  |
//     |-----|
//
// Since only one of A and B can be at the start of C in terms of memory
// layout, at least one of the following can't work:
//
// * naively interpreting a pointer to C as a pointer to A
// * naively interpreting a pointer to C as a pointer to B
struct C : A, B {};

void call_ptm(void (C::*ptm)()) {
    C c;
    // `ptm` could be `A::f` or `B::g`.  We don't know.  At what offset
    // relative to `this` do we expect to find data members then?  It depends
    // on whether `ptm` points to `A::f` or `B::g`, which isn't known at
    // compile time.
    (c.*ptm)();
}
```

One way or another, a pointer to a member function needs to store an offset that can be applied to `this` upon invocation.

Comment: "naively interpreting a pointer to C as a pointer to B" doesn't work, but the assignment of a `B::*ptb` to a `C::*ptc` adjusts the offset is fine. In the same way the assignment `B * b = new C` adjusts the value of the pointer so that it points to the `B` subobject

Comment: But this offset still has to be stored somewhere, which is why I object to the assertion that "a method pointer for a simple class that has no virtual methods can be implemented as a regular pointer to the method".

Comment: Yes, it is stored in the instructions of the program. It is a static value

Comment: How can the `this`-pointer offset be static when it depends on whether `void (C::*ptm)()` holds a pointer to a member function of `A` or of `B`? This isn't known at compile time.

Comment: It holds a pointer to a member function of a `C`, which is known at compile time. The *conversion* from a `void (B::*ptb)()` is not value-preserving

Comment: You mean the compiled program has separate machine code for `B::g` and `C::g`?

Comment: No, the *value* of `ptb` is different to the *value* of `ptc`, by the offset of `B` in `C`

Comment: I don't follow how we can store both the function's address, which is the same regardless of whether we store `B::g` in a `void (B::*)()` or `void (C::*)()`, as well as the `this`-pointer offset in a single value.

Comment: The issue is code using `this->b` inside the body of `B::g`. If `void (C::*ptm)() = &B::g` is just a regular function pointer, then `(c.*ptm)()` can not adjust `this` prior to entering the body of `B::g`, and `this->b` will incorrectly resolve to an address relative to the complete `C` object.